# Office Add-in not supported only in Outlook Desktop Application which uses IE 11 as a default browser

Tags: internet-explorer-11, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

We have an application which is build on Angular. We have created another Outlook Add-in which opens up this application in IE-11 browser. I referred this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/browsers-used-by-office-web-add-ins which says that if your Windows OS is < 1903 then it uses IE 11 as default browser from the outlook app. But it seems that the application shows a blank screen when redirected to the Angular application. But works fine when the add-in is opened from outlook web application using same IE 11 browser. We have tried implementing this solution https://indepth.dev/posts/1125/angular-internet-explorer. But still does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by opening and redirecting to the Angular application? Is the Outlook add-in written in Angular? What code are you using to open the Angular application? If you [attach a debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/attach-debugger-from-task-pane) to the Outlook add-in, do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Have you tried creating any empty add-in project by using the yeoman generator and running it in IE? Does it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a method that blocks ie 11 version 79 and below until there is a fix for it.